# String comparison with struct element

Tags: c++, c

I have piece of code like this in .c file, which detects, whether the tPerson.name is equal to one of the elements of const char* names[COUNT] or not:

```
define COUNT 3
...
typedef struct {
int age;
char *name;
} tPerson;

const char* names[COUNT] = {
    "xxx", "yyy", "zzz"
};
....
char string[128];
strcpy(string, tPerson.name);//tPerson.name is already initizialed
int counter = 0;
while (counter != COUNT) {
    if (strcmp(names[counter], string) == 0) {
        counter++;
        return 0;
    }
}
...
```

All needed libraries are included. Compiler doesnt detect any errors or warnings, but program isnt working as it should - it does nothing after executing. This piece of code is only a part of the huge program, so I'd like to know, whether this construction is correct and somewhere else in the program is error or not. Thanks

Comment: What is the point of `counter++` in your loop after the return statement?

Comment: its already fixed, anyway it wasnt the prime problem.. still not working

Comment: Then update your answer so others don't get confused by it.

Comment: Well, what is the point of `counter++` inside the if-statement at all? It should be outside, because either `strcmp` returns `0` and you return `0` or you keep comparing the same two strings forever, because `counter` is not changed.

Comment: yep youre right, just stupid mistake - counter inside of if instead of while.. thanks

Answer (score 5):

You want to continue the loop if there's no match. Put the statement `counter++;` outside the `if` statement:

```
while (counter != COUNT) {
    if (strcmp(names[counter], string) == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    counter++;
}
```

And use `size_t` for `counter` instead of `int`: `size_t counter = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

You have `return 0` before increasing the counter

```
if (strcmp(names[counter], string) == 0) {
    return 0;
    counter++;
}
```